# One Entity 2 Tables in EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

With EF Core 2.0 is possible to map one entity in 2 tables?

Something similar to this in EF6 (the 2 configurations are equal, they are just samples).

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(delegate(EntityMappingConfiguration<Student> studentConfig)
        {
            studentConfig.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.StudentName });
            studentConfig.ToTable("StudentInfo");
        });

        Action<EntityMappingConfiguration<Student>> studentMapping = m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.Height, p.Weight, p.Photo, p.DateOfBirth });
            m.ToTable("StudentInfoDetail");
        };
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Map(studentMapping);

    }
```

Comment: you mean 2 Forgin key on same table.

Comment: I mean not 2 entities with 1-1 relationship. One entity mapped on two different tables. The two tables, on EF6, have a 1-1 relationship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EF Core 2.0 adds [**Table Splitting**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/#table-splitting) and **Owned Types** (EF6 **Complex Types** replacement), but what you are asking for - **Entity Splitting**, is still not supported.

There is an open feature request [Relational: Entity splitting support #620](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/620) in their GitHib repository, but I don't see any concrete plan/schedule if and when it would eventually be implemented. Most likely when they add TPH inheritance support, but that's just my speculation.

Comment: Could you propose/recommend a way to achieve Entity Splitting in EF Core? I'm [trying to implement TNF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70768409/4778343), but I have some hard time defining 2 tables for one entity.