# Is it possible to move SecurityStamp column to another table (other than AspNetUsers)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, asp.net-identity

It looks like it's possible to ignore certain columns, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559878/asp-net-identity-remove-column-from-aspnetusers-table).

However, if I don't want to totally ignore, e.g. SecurityStamp column, but to move it to a separate table. Is it possible through configuration?

Comment: That's a tough one but I doubt it. You may be able to override UserManager, but the hash and stamp are generated via the manager.

Comment: it looks like it's what Entity Split feature provides, but it's not available in [ef core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768409/map-entity-to-multiple-tables-with-entity-framework-core) at the moment.